# Where is energy lost when a system of capacitors balances itself?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electric-fields, capacitance

Say two identical capacitors are connected like this:
[image: Circuit with 2 capacitors]

Two identical capacitors, each with a capacitance of 1 µF, are connected in parallel, with an open switch in between them.

If a voltage of 100V is applied only on C<sub>1</sub> with the switch open, then it would store an energy of 5 mJ. This is the total initial energy of the system.

Then, if the switch is closed, the charges balance and both capacitors will have a voltage drop of 50V each.  Then, the energy stored in each capacitor will be 1.25 mJ.  That means that the total energy of the system after the switch is closed is 2.5 mJ because there are two capacitors.

But my question is, where did the other 2.5 mJ go? There is no resistor to dissipate any heat. Do the capacitors heat up?

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  I've edited your question a bit to focus on the conceptual side of things; too many calculations can make people think that you're trying to get homework help, which is against our site's rules.  I do think this is a good question, though, and I hope it gets a good answer.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [Two capacitor paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_capacitor_paradox) and the Kirk T. McDonald paper [A Capacitor Paradox](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0312031) explain fully what happens if the wire resistance is zero (very, very small).

Comment: see my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/765758/why-should-this-thermodynamics-problem-be-indeterminate and here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/770099/i-am-not-able-to-understand-what-the-text-is-trying-to-say-about-the-connection

Comment: The lines in a circuit diagram are the edges of a mathematical graph that describes the circuit in Kirchhoff approximation. That approximation does not capture all of the physics of a real circuit. In this case it misses at the very least the resistance and inductance of the actual wires in a physical circuit.